# How did Harvey Dent get away with punching a witness?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

In *The Dark Knight*, beloved "straight arrow" lawyer Harvey Dent punched a witness in court.  In full view of the court he enacted physical violence against a member of the public.

In fairness, the guy did have a gun on him (how he got that into the courtroom I'll never know), so you could argue that it was self-defence. But if you watch the scene you can clearly see Harvey disarmed the man before punching him.  This is a clear violation of self-defense law as the unarmed man no-longer posed a threat.

I am not saying that Harvey behaved in an evil way.  In a life or death scenario we can behave irrationally.  But lawyers have a strict code of conduct when it comes to the courtroom.

How did Harvey maintain his image of being a "straight arrow" lawyer after committing such an obvious violation of courtroom procedure?

Comment: They applauded him after the fact, so I don't think anyone cared about any (if any) violations of procedure. No one cares about the bad guy getting punched.

Comment: An unarmed man can still be dangerous. I'm not sure your question is valid.

Comment: And after rewatching the scene it is clear that the punch and disarming was part of the same action. I can't imagine the law in any civilized country would label this as not self defense.

Comment: The point you raised Gallifreyan is a big part of my main objection to this scene in the movie.  No judge worth his salt would allow that sort of conduct.  I know that Gotham is meant to be a hotbed of crime and whatnot, but that does not excuse Harvey's behaviour.

Comment: I am open to your criticism Ling.  In what way do you think my question is invalid?

Comment: “This is a clear violation of self-defense law as the unarmed man no-longer posed a threat.” Is that right, your honour.

Comment: "A person is privileged to use such force as **reasonably** appears necessary to defend him or herself against an **apparent threat** of **unlawful and immediate violence** from another." Clearly the court deemed neutralising the threat via a disarm and knockout punch reasonable. Not much else to it, I don't think.

Comment: Your question assumes Harvey violated US self-defense law, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: Eloquently put Neo

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The very short answer is that the (would-be) gunman was **still holding the gun when Dent punched him**. Dent grabs the gun and points it toward the floor, but it's not **until he hits him** that he appears to let go.

As such, Harvey's actions would be well within the scope of acting in self-defence and the defence of others within the court.

The [script](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15824910-the-dark-knight-trilogy) direction agrees. Dent grabs the gun but there's no indication that the mobster had let go of it.

> **ROSSI:** *Hostile? I’ll show you hostile.*
>
> Rossi jumps up, points a gun at Dent’s face. Screams from the gallery. Rossi pulls the trigger – the gun misfires with a pop. **Dent steps forward, grabs the gun, decks Rossi with a right cross**, unloads the gun and sets it down in front of Maroni.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Dark Knight Trilogy: The Complete Screenplay](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15824910-the-dark-knight-trilogy)</sup></sub>

The [novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3152869-the-dark-knight?from_search=true) is pretty unequivocal. Grabbing the gun and punching Rossi happened *effectively simultaneously*.

> *Rossi lifted his hand from his side, and somehow it was holding a gun.
> He aimed at Dent’s face, barely four feet away, and pulled the
> trigger. There was a click as the gun’s hammer fell on the firing pin,
> but there was no shot. Dent took a single step forward, **grabbing the
> gun with his left hand as his right, curled into a fist, struck Rossi
> in the mouth.** Rossi slumped back into the witness chair and spat
> blood.*
>
> *Dent ejected the clip from Rossi’s weapon, letting it fall to the
> floor, and crossed to where Maroni sat. He dropped the empty gun onto
> the table in front of Maroni, and said, casually, “Ceramic .28
> caliber. That’s how it beat the metal detectors. Made in China, I
> believe.” Turning back to the witness box, he said, “Mr. Rossi, I
> recommend you buy American.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Dark Knight: Official Novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3152869-the-dark-knight?from_search=true)</sup></sub>

You may also wish to note that the quote addresses the issue (with some slightly altered dialogue) of how he got the gun into the courtroom